# What is the genre of play-by-snail-mail RPGs called?

Tags: play-by-post

I'm looking for games similar to [*De Profundis: Letters from the Abyss*](http://rpggeek.com/rpg/2029/de-profundis), which is a role-playing game played by snail mail, without any face-to-face contact. What is the genre called?

I've tried to search for play-by-mail and play-by-post games, but almost exclusively find games that are played by the Internet. A more specific term would be needed.

Comment: Yeah, it's just play by mail - but people either don't use mail any more or replace it with email/forums because they find it faster, cheaper, and more convenient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a name for the genre.

Play-by-post used to mean that, but the term was taken over by the Internet-meaning at the same time that the popularity of play-by-post (paper mail) dropped off into non-existence. For a lack of common need, no distinguishing term has arisen.

Rather than looking for a term to make searching easier, better to just ask the question here. Something like "A game possible to play by letter mail like De Profundis?" would work. (That said, I don't know of any. It's possible that De Profundis is unique so far.)

Comment: Thanks, I thought that recommendation questions were off-topic here, as on many other SEs. I'll try asking it in a while.

Comment: They're on-topic here only because the field is small and doesn't change nearly as quickly as, say, video games. They still need to be phrased so that they don't just collect a list of equally-valid answers: looking for *one* that suits works, and will get a small, easily-managed list of possible acceptance candidates.

Comment: cf. [Are game recommendation questions on topic?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/1070)

Answer (score 12):

The Style of Game is typically called ***Play By Mail*** or ***PBM***. In the UK, it was also called *Play by Post*, but given the US domination of the early internet, PBP came to mean posts to forums or BBSs. Play by electronic mail is usually called PBEM.

There are a few games I know that are suitable.

Whether they truly cross all the way into "roleplaying" is arguable, but several of the old play-by-mail games are still run on a commercial basis by [Flying Buffalo](http://flyingbuffalo.com/)

[En Garde!](http://www.engarde.co.uk/index.html) (originally by GDW, in print by Margam Evans, Ltd.) is likewise on the border between board game and roleplay, and is well suited to play by mail, play by [forum] post, and play by email.

Lords of Space isn't RPGing, but is a human moderated PBM ruleset for play of space empires at war. It was my first encounter with PBM moderator rulesets for sale, tho it actually postdates En Garde. When I ran it, many of my players got heavy into RP-mode.

Fiasco likewise should be playable that way.

Marvel Universe also should be playable by mail, tho' it would be annoyingly slow to me.

Comment: Fiasco? I can't see how.